# В чем разница вызовов обьекта Executor submit и execute

Tags: java

Какая разница добавления в Executor тасков через  submit и execute

Comment: submit - > можно отправлять Callable/Runnable, а execute - > только Runnable. Так же execute может выполнить Runnable в вызывающем потоке, а не в пуле потоков, в отличии от submit.

Comment: Используйте `submit`, когда надо получить `Future` и из него потом достать результат работы таски